# Antivirus keeps deleting my addins, how do I disable Shadow-Copy in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-debugging, antivirus, shadow-copy, virtual-shadow-copies

So this has become very annoying to me.
Whenever I compile an Outlook Addin, shadow copy creates a copy in the assemblies directory.  My anti-virus then detects the new DLL and promptly deletes it. (Good anti-vurus, no wait, bad anti-virus)

I would rather not exclude the assemblies directory from ALL antivirus scans, so I'm trying to find a way to disable shadow copy in vb.net assemblies during debug. Permanently during development is fine too. Or even a work around would that doesn't leave a gap-ping hole in the antivirus scan would be great.

Everything I found on disabling shadow copy pertains to asp.net, and I cant figure out how to configure it in the vb.net configuration files.

The specifics are: Visual Studio (2010, 2012), Norton Internet Security 22.5.4.24, Outlook 2010, Windows 8.1

Thank you in advance.

JD

Comment: What makes you think it's a "shoadow" copy? Why not a normal copy?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of excluding the entire folder from your antivirus, why not exclude just the file that gets quarantined every time you compile?

Comment: Unfortunately, ShadowCopy, as far as I can tell, generates a random folder under the username\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\ currently the binary resides at ".....\username\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\J89CJ179.KEX\5EHNMA9P.8VQ\fd960ddc\00a04a0b_c97ecf01" which makes it a bit hard for the AV software to know what to exclude or not. The alternative to exluding the filename, would be to exclude the filename across the entire system. Alternatively, I would have to exclude the file when the AV finds it, and then restore it from the quarantine, in and of itself a hassle. Thus, how to disable ShadowCopy.